# Tag Synonym/Merge [Go] and [Golang]

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

From the [go](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go) tag wiki:

> Go, also called ***golang***,

From the [golang](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/golang) tag wiki:

> The term sometimes used for the ***Go*** Programming Language

I think these two tags should probably be made actual synonyms or merged as they both seem to be declaring each other as synonyms.

---

Possibly relevant: There's also somewhat older language called [Go!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go!_(programming_language)) (note the `!`). I'm not sure if we have any questions related to that language currently, but wanted to make a note of it in case it's relevant to how these tags are made into synonyms or merged.

Comment: As someone who isn't a Go developer, is there a preference in the community? To make a synonym or merge, there has to be a source and a target. Which should be the canonical tag?

Comment: Feel free to vote, see link below in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

From the official [Go FAQ](https://go.dev/doc/faq#go_or_golang)

> **Is the language called Go or Golang?**
>
> The language is called Go. The "golang" moniker arose because the web
> site was originally golang.org. (There was no .dev domain then.) Many
> use the golang name, though, and it is handy as a label. For instance,
> the Twitter tag for the language is "#golang". The language's name is
> just plain Go, regardless.

Since "Golang" is a synonym for "Go",  I think we should keep [go](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go), and make [golang](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/golang) a synonym. Note also we currently have 139 questions tagged [go](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go), and only 39 tagged [golang](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/golang).

This is the first time ever I started a synonym voting, hence I had to lookup how it works. Seems whoever has enough rep can now vote on

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/go/synonyms